# cy.click() Failed because this element is being covered by another element

Tags: javascript, testing, cypress, end-to-end, gui-testing

```
    describe.only("DataTable Test", () => {
      beforeEach(() => {
        cy.getDataTableActBtn("@dataTable").as("action-menu");
      });

      it.only("should open view locations modal", () => {
        cy.getDataTableActBtn("@dataTable").as("action-menu");
        cy.get("@action-menu").click();
        cy.getByDataCy("view-locations")
          .should("exist")
          .should("be.visible")
          .click();
        cy.contains("Location List", { matchCase: false }).should("be.visible");
      });
});
```

I tried by applying `click({force: true})`. Still it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

If the button is never visible (according to cypress, then `.should("be.visible")` will always fail.

As you suggest, you can force the click but you need to remove the condition on `be.visible`

```
.should("exist").click({force: true});
```

Comment: If what you say were true, the error message would be different. It would not get to `.click()`.

Comment: Actually, there are two clicks in the test so it may even be the first that fails.